# Filtering a Queryset on multiple values of same attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My `models.py` looks like

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name="Entity Name"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="attribute_values"
    )
    value = models.CharField(max_length=9112,
                             verbose_name="Attribute Value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

and

```
 queryset = Entity.objects.all()
```

Now I wan't to filter all the entities which have attribute values `abc` and `def` i.e

```
for example one entity

   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "XYZ",
        "attribute_values": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "value": "abc",
                "entity": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "value": "def",
                "entity": 1
            },
         ]
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single entity you can do the following:

```
entity.attribute_values.filter(value__in=["abc", "def"])
```

For multiple entities [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) is an option:

```
filtered_attribute_values = AttributeValue.objects.filter(value__in=["abc", "def"])
queryset = Entity.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('attribute_values', queryset=filtered_attribute_values))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

temp = AttributeValue.objects.filter( Q(value='abc') | Q(value='def') )

print(Entity.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('attribute_values', queryset=temp)))
```

In general, Q() objects make it possible to define and reuse conditions. This permits the construction of complex database queries using | (OR) and & (AND) operators; in particular, it is not otherwise possible to use OR in QuerySets.

Detailed explanation is given inside this link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will filter all the entities which have attribute values "abc" or "def":

```
Entity.objects.filter(attribute_values__value__in=["abc", "def"])
```